# How to implement Close button in MVVMCross WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross

I am using *MVVMCross* in my *WPF* application, and I want to provide a *Close* (or *Exit*) button in the GUI to shut-down the entire application. Is there a straightforward way to do this using *MVVMCross* functionality?

I have tried the following approach with my `MainViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private MvxCommand _closeCommand;
    public MvxCommand CloseCommand {
        get { 
            return _closeCommand ?? (_closeCommand = new MvxCommand(DoClose));
        }
    }

    public void DoClose() {
        Close(this);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, to no avail. The `DoClose` method does get called when I press a button that has been bound to `CloseCommand`, but the view-model (and corresponding view) fail to close, even when the WPF `App` `StartupUri` is set to the `MainView`.

Comment: Have you tried Application.Current.Shutdown(); ?

Comment: Thanks, @Nitesh. Ideally however, I would like to manage the application shut-down within a portable view model. `Application.Current.Shutdown` is not available in a PCL "core" project.

Comment: Okay then I would like to get an answer for the question as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many MvvmCross platforms don't support applications closing themselves - this is frowned upon behaviour in iOS, WindowsPhone, Android, WindowsPhone, etc - it isn't supported by public APIs there - so this isn't a common cross-platform request.

However, if you wanted to implement this functionality for those platforms that do support it, then I think perhaps the best place to put this would either be in the presenter or in a custom UI-injected service.

---

To put it in a custom presenter, simply:

- create a custom presenter class (based on [MvxWpfViewPresenter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/MvxWpfViewPresenter.cs))
- return an instance of this class in an override of the `CreatePresenter` method in your your Setup.cs
- override the `ChangePresentation` method in your custom presenter - this method could perhaps use the 'well-known' [MvxClosePresentationHint.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxClosePresentationHint.cs) which is what `Close` sends or it could use a new custom presentation hint you define and send via `ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)` in a ViewModel.

To put this functionality instead in some custom UI service, see N=31 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

---

If you are looking at this shutdown area, then you may also want to consider what steps to take when an application is shutdown (either through user or operating system action). MvvmCross does expose the beginnings of common 'lifetime monitor' hooks within the framework, but actually in practice these are very basic at present - so you may find you need to build your own common layer here.

Comment: Many thanks for an excellent answer (and for *MVVMCross* itself), @Stuart.

Comment: To @Stuart and other interested parties: for what it is worth, please find a sample of a custom WPF view presenter class with basic `Close` support [here](https://gist.github.com/cureos/6053471).