# Where is CreatePresenter in MvxWpfSetup?

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm looking at...
[How to implement Close button in MVVMCross WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783982/how-to-implement-close-button-in-mvvmcross-wpf-application)

I'm trying to create simple WPF app that more or less mimics a droid app and has a back navigation. I'm trying to override CreatePresenter but I can't find it! I've looked in the classes on github but it is not there either.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/b1cb973062b2eb8149f0934f331c4006bc61fa3c/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Platform/MvxWpfSetup.cs

I'm confused. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presenter is a constructor parameter - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/b1cb973062b2eb8149f0934f331c4006bc61fa3c/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Platform/MvxWpfSetup.cs#L25

Comment: Thanks! I did see that but I got confused. I thought that Setup was being created automagically by the framework. I've just found where it is being created in the DoSetup of the App.xaml.cs in the example I'm using.